# From an array of values, make an array of objects having the same key

Tags: underscore.js

Is there a short way in underscorejs to do this?

```
_.SOME_FUNC( [11,22] , 'id' );  
// returns [ {id:11},  {id:22} ]
// all keys are the same
```

Is this already the shortest?

```
_.map([11,22], function (id) { return {id: id};  }  )
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I thought I had seen an underscorejs function to achieve that, but could not find so in doc.  If there is no, I will use `_.map`

Comment: Map is the best solution in this case.